# how do i block a user messaging a bot? discord.js

Tags: discord.js

how do i block a user from my bot?, so if someone messaged the bot it would block that person.. How do you do this i've tried message.author.block() that didn't work and message.member.block() and message.user.block() so how do you block a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have your client officially block a user, although you can do is have it ignore a user given their id.

Here's an example from [How do I block a user from using my bot](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-block-a-user-from-using-my-bot) from the Discord.JS Guide.

```
const blockedUsers = [ 'id1', 'id2' ];
<client>.on('message', message => {
    if (blockedUsers.includes(message.author.id)) return;
});
```

Comment: you know how as a discord user you can block users from messaging you

Comment: My answer still stands: "*You cannot have your client officially block a user*"